# ASP.NET MVC 4 async child action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application targeting .NET 4.5. One of our child actions makes a call out to a web service using HttpClient.

Since we're blocking on IO waiting for the HttpClient response, it makes a great deal of sense to convert the code to the async/await pattern. However, when MVC 4 attempts to execute the child action, we get the following error message:

> HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.

At first glance, it appears as though MVC 4 does not support async/await within a child action. The only remaining option is to run using synchronous code and force a "Wait" on the async task.

As we all know, touching .Result or .Wait() on an async task in an ASP.NET context will cause an immediate deadlock. My async logic is wrapped in a class library, so I can't use the "await blah.ConfigureAwait(false)" trick. Remember, tagging "async" on the child action and using await causes an error, and that prevents me from configuring the await.

I'm painted into a corner at this point. Is there *any* way to consume async methods in an MVC 4 child action? Seems like a flat out bug with no workarounds.

Comment: Could you include the minimal code to show the problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are still parts of MVC that aren't `async`-friendly; I hope these will be addressed in the future. Please do create a Connect or UserVoice issue for this.

> My async logic is wrapped in a class library, so I can't use the "await blah.ConfigureAwait(false)" trick.

You probably *should* add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the calls in your class library (if you can).

You could also hack up an alternate solution. **If** your class library method doesn't need the ASP.NET context, then you could have a thread pool thread do the (a)waiting for you:

```
try
{
    var result = Task.Run(async () => { await MyHttpRequest(...); }).Result;
}
catch (AggregateException ex) { ... }
```

The effect is similar to `ConfigureAwait(false)`: since `MyHttpRequest` runs in a thread pool context, it will not attempt to enter the ASP.NET context when it completes.

Comment: Reviewed some of the more advanced MSDN/Channel 9 videos on async, and saw the exact same recommendation. 

I've updated the code and switched over to blocking on tasks in the child actions - definitely not ideal, but it works. Hopefully they fix the issue in the future. I'll toss my vote up on user voice :)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post links here? Additional resources are always helpful!

Comment: Note the related codeplex and uservoice links are http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601 and http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3233329-support-asynchronous-child-actions. Please vote.

Comment: One interesting optimization I learned is to replace ".Result" with ".GetAwaiter().GetResult()". Avoids the AggregateException mess.

Answer (score 7):

The format of Stephen's answer didn't quite work for me (maybe it's an async noob problem, but hey).

I had to do write the async expression in this format to get a strongly typed return value.

```
Person myPerson = Task.Run(() => asyncMethodWhichGetsPerson(id)).Result;
```