# Error Mvc 5 -> HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete

Tags: c#, view, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-framework-version

I am making my system to use some asynchronous operations, however I came across this error:

**HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.**

I render in my Index which is asynchronous 3 asynchronous Actions and 1 synchronous plus one synchronous Partial.

**Merely illustrative example**

**Controllers**

```
public class Test1Controller : Controller
{
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
   {
      var value = await Get1Async();

      retur View();
   }
}
------------------------------------------
public class Test2Controller : Controller
{
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
   {
      var value = await Get2Async();

      retur View();
   }
}
-------------------------------------------
public class Test3Controller : Controller
{
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
   {
      var value = await Get3Async();

      retur View();
   }
}
------------------------------------------
public class Test4Controller : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      var value = Get4();

      retur View();
   }
}
```

**View**

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("Index", "Test1")

    @Html.Action("Index", "Test2")

    @Html.Action("Index", "Test3")

    @Html.Action("Index", "Test4")

    @Html.Partial("Partial")
</div>
```

I saw that mvc 5 does not support this, is there any way around this situation?

Comment: I believe the odds of people helping you will be more higher if you provide some code. It's not necessary to include full code of your system. Just the part which causes issues without any unnecessary things. Ideally it would a small snippet which reproduce the issue you have. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I made the inclusion of examples.

Comment: I think you need to either switch to the framework version that supports child async actions or make your methods synchronous.

Comment: But be careful, you'll probably will need to wait for your async methods to complete, so this might cause deadlock if you do just like this `Get1Async().Result` or `Get1Async().Wait()`. Actually depends on how `Get1Async` is implemented. So if you need this you can consider this Stephen's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12743302/8715436